# Why do I get segmentation fault when I try to access member data of outer class from nested class?

Tags: c++, nested-class

I have a class Outer with a nested class Inner. Inner has a method 'print' which tries to access a data member of class Outer. The code compiles fine but I get a segmentation fault error when I try to run the programme.

```
#include <iostream>

class Outer{
public:
  Outer();
  ~Outer();

  class Inner{
  public:
    Inner(Outer *parent){}
    void print(){std::cout<< parent-> data <<std::endl;}
  private:
    Outer *parent;
  };
  Inner *obj;

private:
  int data;
};

Outer::Outer(): data(99), obj(new Inner(this)){}
Outer::~Outer(){delete obj;}

int main(){
  Outer outer;
  outer.obj->print();
  return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure what is the issue as I have already passed the 'this' pointer to the inner object.

The code is compiled with g++4.8.2 using the c++11 flag.

Comment: You don't seem to actually initialize `Inner::parent`?

Comment: yes, you have just solved my problem. thank you. Can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must turn on **compiler warnings** and pay attention to them. In this case, the compiler is able to pinpoint the exact error in:

> ```
>  Inner(Outer *parent){}
> ```

```
warning: unused parameter 'parent' [-Wunused-parameter] In constructor 'Outer::Outer()':
```

*(The exact warning message may differ, but all major compilers are able to detect this if you don't prevent them from doing so by using some low default warning level.)*

As you leave the `parent` member variable in an uninitialised status, the following line invokes undefined behaviour because you try to read from the variable:

> ```
>  void print(){std::cout<< parent-> data <<std::endl;}
> ```

You must initialise the member variable:

```
Inner(Outer *parent) : parent(parent) {}
```

---

That's not the only problem, though. There's also this:

```
18:7: warning: 'Outer::data' will be initialized after [-Wreorder]
15:10: warning: 'Outer::Inner* Outer::obj' [-Wreorder]
21:1: warning: when initialized here [-Wreorder]
```

You can fix it by simply changing the order as follows:

```
Outer::Outer(): obj(new Inner(this)), data(99) {}
```

Answer (score 6):

You are not storing the pointer to the `Outer` class in the `Inner` constructor:

```
Inner(Outer *parent) : parent(parent) {}
```

Also, if you use C++11, this may be a good case to use smart pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything with `parent` in

```
Inner(Outer *parent){}
```

You need to `Inner`s `parent` member in the constructor

```
Inner(Outer *parent_) : parent(parent_){}
```